# What is best practice when using Entity Framework with WCF in the client user interface?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wcf

I have a single VS2010 solution with the following projects:

1. `Nova.ClientProxy` -- provides a WCF `NovaDataService` on the server machine.
2. `Nova.Data` -- provides an Entity Framework model used by the WCF service on the server machine.
3. `Nova5.UI` -- is the user interface on the client machine.

The `Nova5.UI` on the client obtains its data by a service reference to the server's `NovaDataService`.

Is it best practice to have the Nova5.UI on the client only use entities from its service reference or just the `Nova.Data` project (that is the base project for the server), or both?

If I use both, there is often a confusion in the Nova5.UI where an entity exists in both the service reference and in `Nova.Data`. But if I don't use both I get errors like:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Nova5.UI.DataService.EncounterDetail[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'    C:\Nova5\Nova5.UI\ViewModels\DoctorDesk\DoctorDeskViewModel.cs  304 40  Nova5.UI

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The above error comes from code like this:

```
 this.dataservice.GetEncounterDetailsCompleted += (s, e) =>
         {
            try
            {
                Encounterdetails = e.Result;
            }
            catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException ex)
            {
                Msgbox.ShowMessage(ex.InnerException.ToString(), "Connection Error");
            }
        };
```

Comment: You would use whatever is returned by the services, which presumably are serialisable entities defined in Nova.ClientProxy.

Comment: @bonyjoe But how then to manage extensions like Clone(), etc., That currently depend on the partial class defined in the entity framework within the Nova.Data project?

Comment: @AlanWayne - If the client depends on anything from the service (beyond the metadata, which will not include concepts like partial classes or interfaces) then I would suggest revisiting your design, as you are tightly coupling the client and the service and defeating one of the purposes of web services and SOA.  So yes, best practice would normally favor metadata only.  Another alternative would be to have an assembly of shared types that both the service and the client reference, but that only works if you're doing .NET to .NET.

Comment: @Tim To me this sounds like an answer.

Comment: @Tim Me too. I would mark it as an answer if I could. In my situation, I am gathering that it would be better to couple the viewmodel to its own entityframework filled from the service, then it would be to depend simply on the metadata from the service. Thanks.